# Transient current limiting

Tags: usb

I have a USB powered system. The system on occasion for a short period of time, needs more than 500mA. I have additional caps that can provide this current.

The problem is, despite these caps have enough power in them, during the excess current phase, I see the USB rail goes down 0.2V. This is probably ok for my application but I like to be cautious since I am worried some hosts out there doesn't like this behaviour and may disconnect me from the host.

I am looking for a simple solution where during the transient USB current is limited to 500mA. I have seen some ICs that can do this but I prefer a discrete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a simple solution where during the transient USB
>   current is limited to 500mA. I have seen some ICs that can do this but
>   I prefer a discrete solution.

In order to limit current a circuit needs to measure current. This is usually done with a series resistor in line with the load. But, the resistance has to be small so that it doesn't not "drop" too much voltage in normal operation. A 0.1 ohm series resistor will drop 50mV at 500mA and this is probably acceptable.

However, to measure this small volt drop accurately (in order to determine current), requires a fairly decent amplifier and to make this from discrete components is, in my opinion, foolish.